# Combine two columns and perform a where operation on the result

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have two columns, one for 'firstName' and one for 'lastName'. I'm trying to perform a where operation on the concatenation of those two columns to match for a full name.

Here is what I've tried:

```
select * from table where concat_ws(' ', 'firstName', 'lastName') like '%some_value%'
```

This just returns a blank array.

**Example Data:**

| firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- |
| Clayton | Smith |
| Barbara | Clayman |
| Sam | Peterson |

*when some_value = Clay, it should return 'Clayton Smith' and 'Barbara Clayman'*

I got a lot of this syntax from some other stackoverflow answers which were marked as solutions to a similar problem, however when implementing this myself I couldn't get it to work.

FWIW I'm going to be building these queries with knex.js so if there's a knex.js specific solution feel free to answer with that.

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: Updated with some data

Comment: That's a literal string pattern. You need to concatenate the variable/parameter with percent characters. You seem to expect interpolation to happen there.

Comment: @shawnt00 can you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to your `CONCAT_WS` call should be in double quotes. If they're in single quotes, Postgres will interpret them as string literals. This should work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', "firstName", "lastName") ILIKE '%some_value%'
```

I also recommend using `ILIKE` rather than `LIKE` - this will make the pattern matching for your search term be case insensitve.

Answer (score 0):

use `STR_POS`

The PostgreSQL strpos() function is used to find the position, from where the substring is being matched within the string.

[https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/strpos-function.php#:~:text=The%20PostgreSQL%20strpos()%20function,being%20matched%20within%20the%20string.&text=Example%20of%20PostgreSQL%20STRPOS(),within%20the%20argument%20is%205](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/strpos-function.php#:%7E:text=The%20PostgreSQL%20strpos()%20function,being%20matched%20within%20the%20string.&text=Example%20of%20PostgreSQL%20STRPOS(),within%20the%20argument%20is%205).

`select * from table where strpos(concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name),'Clay') > 0`

Replace literal with variable